# How to get value from a dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value from a "p" element, I draw this "p" with jQuery and it's ok, then I have a button and when I click on it I want to display the value from "p" element but I don't get any information, here is a simple code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#c').click(function() {
    var p = $('#p1').val();
    alert(p);
  });

  draw();
});


function draw() {
  var html = "";
  html += '<p id="p1">Hi</p>';

  $('#d').html(html);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="c">Click</button>
<hr />
<div id="d">
</div>
```

How can I solve this? I don't get any console error.

Comment: `val()` method can be only used on form elements like input, select or textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change :

```
var p = $('#p1').val();
```

To :

```
var p = $('#p1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` only returns the value from `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements. If you just want to read the content of an element, you should use `.text()` or `.html()`. The first returns just the text, and the second – HTML content of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quote from jQuery

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty
>   collection, it returns undefined.

So as @ehsan suggested, use `.text()` method if you want to get content as text.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is used to get the value of `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements.

If you want to get the text inside an element (e.g: *div*, *p*, etc), you need to use `.text()`.

So, in your case, you need to change this:

```
var p = $('#p1').val();
```

for this:

```
var p = $('#p1').text();
```

Note: If you want the full html code inside an element, you need to use `.html()`.

Sources:

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `var p = $('#p1').html();`